# How can I view what is being sent out in Savon

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

So I have something like this...

```
require 'savon'    
client = Savon.client do
  wsdl 'OnboardingServices?wsdl'
  pretty_print_xml true 
end  
response = client.call(:recruiter_onboarding_request)
```

How can I view what is actually being sent out to the Soap server?

Comment: You should be able to see the request in your log since you have the `pretty_print_xml` option set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 2.x I usually build my client like this:

```
require 'savon'

client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: "http://www.some-server.com/service?wsdl",
  pretty_print_xml: true,
  log: true,
  log_level: :debug
)

puts client.operations
resp = client.call(:some_method,
                   message: { :some => "key", :and => "another one" }
                  )
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was obvious from accepting the answer.

Comment: obviously :-). But at the time I wrote my comment there had been no traffic on this question. Never mind.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't see that there when I accepted it and thought that it was new as I saw it for the first time today.